# Is my setup correct for dual monitor (one for gaming )(one for my streaming)?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, vga, displayport

My gpu can handle 2 monitors (i checked) my first or main output was by hdmi to hdmi leaving the dvi - d and the displayport vacant. My second monitor is a vga input therefore i bought an adapter DP to VGA but my pc cant read it i already checked if my drivers were updated, they were. Is it possible that my cable/adapter is defective?

Answer (score 0):

DP, DVI and HDMI are all digital video signal standards.

VGA on the other hand is analog.

There is an exception to DVI, where there are three standards:

`DVI-I`: Integrated. Supports analog and digital in the same connector.

`DVI-D`: Digital only.

`DVI-A`: Analog only.

Converting from digital to analog is not possible without an active converter. Those are more expensive than passive connectors, which I assume is what you have in hand and why it doesn't work.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Overview):

> For analog VGA/YPbPr and dual-link DVI, a powered active adapter is
>   required for compatibility and does not rely on dual mode. Active VGA
>   adapters are powered by the DisplayPort connector directly, while
>   active dual-link DVI adapters typically rely on an external power
>   source such as USB.